# how to use qstring as char array

Tags: unicode, qstring, arrays

I  am trying to write a function which finds out is this word georgian or not. I wrote it for latin characters and it worked. now i am trying to change it to read a QString char by char and compare to georgian first and last letter. how can I do that? What I do wrong?

```
bool Georgianword(QString &sit)
{ int i=0;

      QByteArray ba = sit.toUtf8();
while (i<sit.size())
{
    if (ba[i]<'ა' || ba[i]>'ჰ')
        break;
    i++;
}

return (i==sit.size());

}
```

Comment: In what way does your code go wrong?

Comment: I don't know Georgian but from this UTF-8 page for Georgian characters (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/georgian/utf8test.htm), it looks like the letters you are checking for are only lowercase letters. But you are not checking for uppercase letters. Does your test input have any uppercase characters?

Comment: no there is no uppercase characters in georgian

Answer (score 0):

If you encode the string as UTF-8, you are dealing with UTF-8 code units (single bytes which might be only part of a multi-byte sequence), not code points. The best solution is to simply use a QString iterator:

```
for (QString::iterator it = sit.begin(); it != sit.end(); ++it) {
    if (*it < 'ა' || *it > 'ჰ') {
        ...
    }
}
```